# Evaluate general normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ by scaling to $N(0,1)$. Why does integrals result in same value?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is a normal RV, $\sigma \neq 0$.

To calculate $P(a < X < b)$ we must compute $$\int^a_b \frac {1} {\sigma \sqrt {2 \pi}} e^{-\frac {(x-\mu)^2} {2\sigma^2}} \, dx$$

However we cannot easily compute this value, so we scale $X$ resulting in a new RV $Z = \frac {X - \mu} {\sigma} \sim N(0,1)$.

Now to compute $P(a < X < b)$ we simply evaluate $$\int^{\frac {a-\mu} {\sigma}}_{\frac {b-\mu} {\sigma}} \frac {1} { \sqrt {2 \pi}} e^{-\frac {x^2} {2}} \, dx$$, which can be done in a table for the standard normal distribution.

**However can someone tell me why these two integrals result in the same value ?**

Also, to evaluate $P(a < X < b)$ by $$\int^a_b \frac {1} {\sigma \sqrt {2 \pi}} e^{-\frac {(x-\mu)^2} {2\sigma^2}} \, dx$$ are there other methods than scaling to a standard normal variable $Z$ ?

Comment: Substitute $t=(x-\mu)/\sigma$.

Comment: In the original integral ? Im aware that if one has a RV $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then we can transform it to a $\sim N(0,1)$ RV by subtracting $\mu$ and dividing by $\sigma$, but why does this apply the probabilities are the same after changing limits accordingly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
P = \frac {1} {\sigma \sqrt {2 \pi}}\int^a_b  e^{-\frac {(x-\mu)^2} {2\sigma^2}}dx
$$

Forgetting what you know about probability, let's use calculus to change variables in the above integral. Let 
$$z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma},$$
then $dz=\frac{dx}{\sigma}$. For the limts, when $x=b$, $z=\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}$. When $x=a$, $z=\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}$. Finally, the argument of the exponential, in terms of $z$, is $-\frac{z^2}{2}$Substituting all of that into the integral to change variables, we get

$$
P = \frac {1}{\sqrt {2 \pi}}\int^{\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}}_{\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}}  e^{-\frac {z^2} {2}}dz
$$

So, changing variables allows us to kind of standardize things, instead of having a single table for every combination of $\mu,\sigma$, which would be quite a lot of pages of tables!

As for your other question about evaluating the integral directly, it has a closed form expression in terms of [error functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). These are tabulated in books as well, and modern calculators often have implementations of the values as well. You could just as easily calculate the integral by numerical quadratures, to any precision you desire. This is likely how the error function or z-tables were generated to begin with.

Comment: Thank you. May one use integration by substitution if we cant find the antiderivative of normal distribution ? I mean the proof of substitution method is based on knowing the antiderivative as stated on Wikipedia.

Comment: Anti-derivatives of the function $e^{-z^2/2}$ exist; even if you "can't find" them, or didn't know that they had special names, the area under the curve $e^{-z^2/2}$ on intervals of the real line is a well defined number for every interval. If you give me an interval, I can give you the definite integral to any finite number of digits of precision you like, for example, using simple Riemann sum approximations to the integral. Doing so, I could generate the tables you find in books, and come up with algorithms for a calculators or computer to produce finite precision values of this integral.

Comment: Aha, so there exists some implicit function (antiderivative) even thus we cannot give an explicit formula for it. However how can one determine the values of the definite integral ? We must find some value $L$ and for any $\epsilon > 0$ give some partition size $\delta$ such that the value of any partition $- L$ is less than $\epsilon$ for partition size smaller than $\delta$ ? But how can we do this if we dont know $L$ ? Using a computer gives an idea of this $L$, but how to we prove the limit is actually $L$ using approximations ?

Comment: This is really a separate question. Answering it would require more space than is available here. Maybe post another question and put a link here? Practically you construct a sequence of approximants $L_n$ that depend on a monotonically decreasing sequence of $\delta$ values, and then show that $|L_{n+1}-L_{n}|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$ and for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. I think that establishes convergence without needing the limiting value $L$. This is how computer algorithms would work as well; $L_{N+1}$ approximates $L$ with $-\log_{10}(\epsilon)$ digits of precision.

Comment: "I think that establishes convergence without needing the limiting value L". This just proof there exist some $L$, but even thus we make partition size arbitary small, we still cannot conclude the value of the definite integral, we just approximate it ? I mean one could argue that given a partition we can select lower/upper bound in each interval and then calculate upper and lower bound for the value of the definite integral, then as these values go closer one has an approximation of the definite integral, but not the exact value.

Comment: In the way I think of this, yes, you can approximate it to arbitrary precision without being able to "conclude the value". This is not that remarkable. Consider a simpler analogy, the number  $\sin(1)$. How do you "know" this value? You can calculate it to any finite precision by a sequence of approximants (e.g. the $N$-order Taylor polynomial for $\sin$ evaluated at $1$) that converges to a limiting value, and we have an error bound $\epsilon$ for every order $N$ of the approximation. The situation is completely analogous to the integral under discussion. Does calculating $\sin(1)$ worry you?

Comment: What I'm arguing is that the definite integrals under question are DEFINED by the limit of a sequence, just like $\sin$ can be DEFINED as the limit of a sequence of partial sums. We often don't "know" the value of such things, but if convergence to a limiting value can be proven, and an algorithm prescribed to calculate approximants with error bound decreasing to zero, then we can say that $\sin(1)$ or $\text{erfc}(x)$ is DEFINED as the limit of the finite procedure I described.

Comment: The error bound in calculating $\sin$ as a Taylor series is the Taylor error, right ? Do we have such an error bound, like the Taylor error, when calculating definite integrals ? I mean is there some function giving the error bound for $N$ ? Also when computing the definite as a sequence, you refer to the Riemann integral (regular partition) with points in intervals taken as the midpoints, and then the sequence of $N$ is the number of slices of the interval ?

Comment: The error bound in the case of $\sin$ can be given by various formulas for the Taylor "remainder" term (Lagrange, Cauchy forms), but I had the alternating series error bound in mind. For convergent sequences of Riemann sums of decreasing partition size, estimates of the error bound that go to zero can be found, but I'm not familiar with the particulars off the top of my head. If you're interested further, I suggest you open another question.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a routine substitution (and don't confuse the letter $u$ with the letter $\mu$):

\begin{align}
u & = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \\[10pt]
du & = \frac{dx}{\sigma}
\end{align}

As $x$ goes from $a$ to $b$, then $u$ goes from $\dfrac{a-\mu}{\sigma}$ to $\dfrac{b-\mu}{\sigma}$.

Comment: Thank you.  How does one write the antiderivative of the normal distribution ? How are the values of the distribution calculated without ? To be more specific how are the values of standard normal distribution calculated ? And can we do substitution integration without antiderivative since proof is based on antiderivative ?

Comment: The cumulative distribution function, which is the antiderivative of the density function, lacks an "elementary" expression, meaning it can be expressed in various ways by integrals or infinite series, but computing its values (which are what you see in the table in the back of most elementary statistics books) requires a lot of numerical computation.  I could say something about how to do that, but not about how to do it _efficiently_ (I've only seen that barely touched on in courses a couple of times).  Perhaps that could be the topic of another question submitted here.

Comment: On modern computers, the values can be calculated very quickly to machine precision. One approach is to remap the infinite interval to a finite one, and then use a finite polynomial basis to represent the density function to machine precision. Then the distribution function has a simple representation in the same polynomial basis, and values in the table are calculated by evaluating the polynomial. In my investigations, a 110th order polynomial on $(-1,1)$, remapped to the infinite interval $(-\infty,\infty)$, is enough to represent the distribution function to 16 digits of precision.

Comment: For examples of this approach, see the Chebfun project, particularly, here: http://www2.maths.ox.ac.uk/chebfun/examples/stats/html/NormalExercises.shtml